# Solve this difficult rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

There is a very difficult rebus. Try to solve this. The rebus is as follows:

[image: Image of rebus]

**Hint-1:**

> The answer isn't a number.

**Hint-2:**

> 0.08333 means 0.08333... , I mean 1/12

Comment: Just something I figured 0.08333 is 1/12

Comment: Hint on how to use the 0.83333?

Comment: the orientation of the 0.08333 in the picture might be relevant.. some how

Comment: I think it may be time for a hint.

Comment: Does the OP even know the answer?

Comment: 1/12 of 15 is 1.25

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> 16

because

> Two eyes = II = 2.
> The egg = 0, because of its shape. In tennis, a score of zero is called "love" because "l'oeuf" is French for "the egg." So, the top of the fraction is 20.
> The bottom is fif-tin (fifteen) twelfths, which is 5/4.
> 20 divided by 5/4 equals 16.

I'm not sure this is correct, but hopefully parts of it are.

Comment: This is not my answer.

Comment: Guys, it is a rebus. My question is what does this rebus mean to say, I don't want to know what is the number.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a thought:

> M. L. KING BIRTHDAY ON FIFTEEN JANUARY (or, in American date notation, M. L. KING BIRTHDAY ON JANUARY FIFTEEN)

Explanations:
Top left:

> We have some eyes looking intently:
>  "AM LOOKING"

Top right:

> We have a chick hatching, or its:
>  "BIRTH DAY"

Horizontal Line:

> Designates that we have some stuff atop other stuff, or:
>  "ON"

Bottom left:

> We have a TIN inscribed with 'FIF' (FIFTIN):
>  "FIFTEEN"

Bottom right:

> 1/12, or "1 of 12", which is commonly:
>  "JANUARY"

Putting it all together we get:

> AM LOOKING BIRTH DAY ON FIFTEEN JANUARY
>  Which sounds a lot like M. L. KING BIRTHDAY ON FIFTEEN JANUARY (or, in American date notation, M. L. KING BIRTHDAY ON JANUARY FIFTEEN)

Which we will note

> Occurs a few days after this puzzle was posted (Jan 9), so perhaps it was on the op's mind
>  Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr._Day

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> Isaac Overcan XII, monarch of Puzzling Exchange!!

Actually,

> I am pretty sure that it is Isaac (eyes + egg), but the other part eludes me.  Maybe that will help (or hinder) someone.

Based on the comment by J.Siebeneichler...

> Genesis 26 - Isaac 12-15 (eyes + egg + 1/12 (inverse due to math) + fif + tin)

The relevant passages taken from [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2026%3A12-15&version=KJV) are reproduced below.

> **Genesis 26:12-15**
>  <sup>12</sup> Then Isaac sowed in that land, and received in the same year an hundredfold: and the Lord blessed him.
>  <sup>13</sup> And the man waxed great, and went forward, and grew until he became very great:
>  <sup>14</sup> For he had possession of flocks, and possession of herds, and great store of servants: and the Philistines envied him.
>  <sup>15</sup> For all the wells which his father's servants had digged in the days of Abraham his father, the Philistines had stopped them, and filled them with earth.

Comment: I'm thinking the "fif" on a tin suggests "fifteen".

Comment: Why chapter 26?

Comment: @Bachrach44 - because that is where verses 12 to 15 are.

Comment: @APrough Almost every chapter of every book of the bible has at least 15 verses. Wherever you look you will find verses 12-15. Additionally the fact that the 15 comes first in the rebus makes it far more likely that the solution is 15:12. This is all of course assuming the presence of the word Isaac makes it a biblical reference which seems fairly speculative to me.

Comment: @Bachrach44 - I agree, but this whole thing is speculative, correct?  I mean, it is a difficult rebus (OP's term), and, yes, I am going on the fact that Isaac is an important clue.  Of any Google search I have done, the words Isaac, 12, and 15 only point to that particular passage of the bible.

Comment: This is not my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just some jottings of a (partial) answer to each part separately.

The top part:

> Looking chic

The bottom part:

> Fifteen to the dozen ([talking very fast](http://it.cultura.linguistica.inglese.narkive.com/aLDfXte2/fifteen-to-the-dozen))

Reasoning for the bottom part:

> *fif* tin = fifteen = 15
>  0.03888 is close to 1/12
>  15 * 1/12 = 15/12, also written as 15:12, which can be read as 'fifteen to 12'

Comment: (I'm not sure what I've done wrong with the formatting of the bottom part - please feel free to edit to hide the bottom section.)

Comment: The issue was that you had blank lines between the >! I fixed it.

Comment: This is not my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is:

> **64**

Because:

> The eyes resembles in shape a rotated $8$.
>  The egg resembles $0$.
>  The can is $15$ (thanks to [J. Siebeneichler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/solve-this-difficult-rebus#comment180680_59016)).
>  $0.08333$ is $\frac{1}{12}$. (this also proves numbers can be rotated)
>  The black line is a fraction.

So:

> $$\frac{80}{15\frac1{12}} = \frac{12 \times 80}{15} = 64$$

Comment: Guys, it is a rebus. My question is what does this rebus mean to say, I don't want to know what is the number.

Comment: @IQWANTER It's been 10 days now, maybe a hint will help narrowing down the answers.

Comment: I think for the last part, you should write $15\frac12$ as $15\times \frac12$ to avoid confusion of [mixed fractions](https://www.mathsisfun.com/mixed-fractions.html).

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> $10$

Reasoning:

> Top part is to be rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise, it reads "$08$".
>  Bottom part is fifteen ("fif" on a tin) multiplied by $0.08333..$, the result is $\frac54$.
> Multiplying the number obtained from the top part by the number obtained from the bottom part, we obtain $8\times\frac54=64$.

Comment: Guys, it is a rebus. My question is what does this rebus mean to say, I don't want to know what is the number.

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be:

> Ice age

I can barely take credit for this as I thought about this by all the other answers.

While I first also thought of

> Issac

the answer by @Lawrence made me think about reading it even faster.

> As stated in his answer fif + tin can (*) [often omitted in math] 1/12 = 15:12 fifteen to the dozen. The instruction to read the upper part really fast.

Lastly

> egg was odd because the chick is in the process of hatching

So it is:

> Eyes hatch (very fast) --> Ice age

Comment: But what about the bottom half of the rebus? Your answer only mentions the top half.

Comment: @F1Krazy I edited the answer to make it clearer. I basically took the part directly from Lawrence's answer. I never heard that saying before. English is not my first language though, that's why I said I can barely take credit for this answer as it's based of another. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think the Answer is

> Father

First part:

> Isaac(Eyes + Egg)
>  Isaac appears in the book of Genesis.

The second part is about

> The 15th(fif + tin)

The 0.833:

> I thought the 1/12(0.833) means 1 out of 12

So I came to the solution:

> The 15th Word in the 1st verse of the 12th chapter in the book of genesis is **father**